# Calculating partial derivative of multivariable function

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

I want to calculate the derivative $\frac{d F}{d t}$ of a function $F(x(t),y(t),t)$.
So i need to calculate $\frac{d F}{d t} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial 
t}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$. Is this the right way?

Comment: Your function is $G(t) = F(x(t), y(t), t)$. Use the chain rule to compute $\frac{dG}{dt}(t)$.

Comment: If $x(t),y(t)$ are constants, then the expression for $\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}$ you wrote is $0$ because then $\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}=0$. But the derivative of $F$ itself shouldn't be $0$ because $F$ might change as $t$ changes because $F$ depends on $t$ through its third argument.

Answer (score 1):

> So i need to calculate $\frac{d F}{d t} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial 
> t}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$. Is this the right way?

Almost.  $F(x(t),y(t),t)$ has three arguments, so applying the Chain Rule::$$\frac{d F}{d t} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial 
t}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}\frac{\partial t}{\partial t}$$

Where, of course, $\tfrac{\partial t}{\partial t}=1$.